# What does a "toothless walnut" mean?

Tags: meaning, literature, simile

I'm looking for the meaning of this sentence taken from *[Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone](http://www.deepcenter.org/deepcenter/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/leaky-cauldron_jk-rowling-1.pdf)*:

> A little man in a top hat was talking to the old bartender, who was quite bald and looked like a **toothless walnut**.

Comment: He looked like a walnut. One without teeth. Though a farcical statement (walnuts don't have teeth), it's clear what the meaning is. Such a whimsical style of writing, rather surreal, is considered acceptable (even amusing) in less formal  literary / conversational registers.

Comment: Walnuts have ***"wrinkles"*** or are "wrinkly**. That's why she wrote it. Instead of saying: a toothless, wrinkled old man. Gees.....cliché avoidance is the  point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

walnut  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/walnut)

> corrugated seed of any of these trees

and

toothless  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/toothless)

> 1. toothless - lacking teeth toothless -  "a toothless old crone" [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english-thesaurus/crone)
> 2. toothless - lacking necessary force for effectiveness

We get (with poetic license) a toothless corrugated seed = a **toothless walnut**: Old, wrinkled and metaphorically without teeth, or old and ineffectual.

Comment: A walnut looks wrinkly like an  old man's face.

Answer (score -4):

This must be a tricky case :) for language skill maintenance I read Harry Potter in all languages I know, French, German, Italian, Russian. Apparently all translators struggled hard to decipher what a 'toothless walnut' could mean.
in French: une noix scintillante ( a shimmering walnut)
in Italian: una noce di gomma ( a rubber nut )
in German: eine klebrige Walnuss ( a sticky walnut)
So they all kept walnut but all eliminated toothless regardless of possible linguistical or poetical reasoning. This made me think that the original text might have a typo. And voilà, in my opinion 'a toothless walrus' makes much more sense.

Comment: All those translators stuck with *nut* as you say, and I doubt they were working from retail editions so could have been kept informed of errata.

Comment: Good translations are poetic. I think the translators were not interested in a literal translation of "toothless walnut". They were aiming to poetically translate – create a funny and true image using the new language. In the French edition, *une noix scintillante* refers to the shininess of a bald head. In the German and Italian, *una noce di gomma* or *eine klebrige Walnuss* describes the shape of the bald head as like a gum or rubber eraser. Each different in detail, but each funny and true. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't understand why this has so many downvotes. It is extremely interesting. The problem with many translators is that they don't have any imagination. The French could have been: une noix édentée, to mirror the English.  The only issue for me is the poster saying there was a typo. Baldness was the point: wrinkles were the point. Walnuts have wrinkles.

Comment: Walruses are smooth; they do not have wrinkles, in fact. But maybe you are right. In any case, I liked finding out those translations.

Comment: @Lambie I believe that "gomma" can stand for "gomma da masticare" which means *chewing gum*, and gum that has been chewed has "creases"= "wrinkles". Although saying that, "gomma" is also Italian for "eraser/rubber" but I've never heard a small eraser being called *una noce" (nut-sized) before.

Comment: @Mari-Lou I was only criticizing the French. A noce di gomma would back-translate as just  a rubber nut. The chewing gum part does not "go through"; but I was discussing the French.

Comment: And I was talking about the Italian. Gomma can also mean *tyre* (tire) so maybe the translator was thinking of the tread marks? Who knows. "Toothless walnut" has no ambiguity, it's a very clever description. I much prefer it. A toothless walrus doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Lambie I found this answer the most informative, in all directions. Not only is translation hard, just understanding the original is hard. It's poetry; walnuts don't have teeth.